# How to delete selected data from database using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, sql-delete

`jdbcData.jsp` this shows the result of whole rows 
and columns of table `reg` with action link 
delete. I want to delete that only 
data row on when clicked on delete 
link. What should i do?

**note:** second scriptlet is named as jdbcDelete.jsp.

***jdbcData.jsp***

```
 <% 
     Statement st =null;
     ResultSet rs =null;
     String s1 = request.getParameter("fn");
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innoventa","root","root");

     st =con.createStatement();
     rs=st.executeQuery("select * from reg");
 %>
 <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10dx" summary="all posts" >

 <tr>
     <td><b>Id</b></td>
     <td><b>First Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Action</b></td>
 </tr>

 <% 
     while(rs.next()) {          
         int a = rs.getInt("id");
         String b =rs.getString("fname");
         String c=rs.getString("lname");
 %>
 <tr>
     <td><%out.println(a);%></td>
     <td><%out.println(b);%></td>
     <td><%out.println(c);%></td>
     <td><a href="jdbcDelete.jsp?id1=<%=a%>">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
 <%
     }
 %>
 </table>
 <%
     st.close();
     con.close();
 %>
```

***jdbcDelete.jsp***

```
<% Integer dlt =(Integer)request.getAttribute("id1");
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement st=null;

    rs = st.executeQuery("delete from reg where id='"+dlt+"'");
    response.sendRedirect("jdbcData.jsp");
%>
```

Comment: Please switch to using [`PreparedStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Your `DELETE` is vulnerable to SQL injection; the whole table will get erased when someone passes in id `' OR 1=1 --`.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion But I am learner. prepared statement ll be tought us in next  JDBC lecture.Today's lecture was about to connect jdbc with regestration form. but i want to learn more so i decided to do this and got error.
i ll be very thank full if anyone give me the solution of it
@mick Mnemonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of reason why your code is not working.

1. In **jdbcDelete.jsp** there is no connection object present so you need to establish connection first

   ```
   <% 
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innoventa","root","root");
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
   %>
   ```
2. You are using `request.getAttribute("id1");` to get `ID` and you have not set any attribute in page `jdbcData.jsp` so you will get `null`. You need to use `request.getParameter("id1");` instead, `request.getParameter("id1");` always returns `String` so you need to parse `String` to `int`. To do that

   ```
   int dlt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id1"));
   ```
3. You are executing `executeQuery` which returns `ResultSet`.

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet
>   object.

Here you need to use `executeUpdate` which is used to execute `DML` commands like `INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE` and it returns `int`.

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("delete from student where studentid="+dlt);
```

So finally you **jdbcDelete.jsp** looks like:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% 
    int dlt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id1"));
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innoventa","root","root");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();;  

    int i = st.executeUpdate("delete from student where studentid="+dlt);
    if (i != 0) {
        response.sendRedirect("jdbcData.jsp");
    } else {
        out.print("Data not deleted successfully");
    }
%>
```

**Suggestion:** It is bad practice to use java code in JSP instead use `servlets`, also use `preparedstatement` but as you are learning by time you will learn.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks a lot bro. i too wanting to do all the things perfect but to become number 1 there are 99 in between to beat up so tring my best to come up ASAP with all good knowledge as same as yours.thanks again for this.it absolutly worked. i wish i can have friend like you so i can learn quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your code like this,

```
<% Integer dlt =(Integer)request.getAttribute("id1");
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement st=null;

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from reg where id=?")
ps.setInt(1,dlt);
ps.executeUpdate();

response.sendRedirect("jdbcData.jsp");
%>
```

NB:-For database operation you can write services or DAO
And please go through [MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/basic_mvc_architecture.htm) architecture